# Importing a file in the same sub-directory of a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is structured in the following way:

```
proj/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    subdir/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
          module2.py
```

`module1.py` uses `module2.py`. and `main.py` uses `module1.py` and `module2.py`

I managed to make it work:

`import subdir.module1` and `import subdir.module2` in `main.py`

`from .module2 import Module2` in `module1.py`

The problem I'm currently facing is making the `module1` an executable script. When trying to run it directly I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                   
  File "module1.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                             
    from .module2 import Module2                                                                                                     
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.module2'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Is there a way to make the modules inside the subdirectory directly executable while still being import-able from the main script?

The code for main.py:

```
import subdir.module1 as module1                                                                                                     
import subdir.module2 as module2                                                                                                     

module1.main()
```

The code for module1.py:

```
from .module2 import Module2                                                                                                         

class Module1:
    pass

def main():
    m = Module2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code for module2.py:

```
class Module2:
    pass
```

The __init__.py files are empty

Comment: It would help us to answer if you add your code in `main.py`.

Comment: Added the code. This is just a small example of what I'm trying to do in a real project though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python follows an execution model very close to regular programs on your computer. The program (or python script) is located somewhere on the `$PATH` and any libraries it loads (or python module) is in some different system defined location. Python intends to be installed. Scripts are placed on the PATH and modules are buried somewhere in the python directories.

One exception is that when you run a script, python adds its directory to the python path for modules. So any of its subdirectories that happen to have an `__init__.py` become python packages. When you run `main.py`, it is a script and `subdir` is a package. That lets `module1.py` do package relative imports. Interestingly, `main.py` itself isn't in a package, the `__init__.py` at its level is not imported.

When you run `module1.py` as a script, it isn't a package either. So package relative imports no longer work.

The solution is to go through the pain of making all of this an installable package. You define a setup.py and, well, there are multiple options on how to set things up there. [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a good resource. One thing to notice is the [`console_scripts`](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) parameter that will auto-generate scripts from module entry points.

Its a large hill to climb but as projects go beyond one or two modules, worth the pain.

Comment: I guess this is the correct solution. I'll accept it even though it is a complete overkill for my problem. I ended up wrapping the imports with a try-except and import in another way if an exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything is related to the 'current working directory'. This is often the folder form which you run your original code, irrespective of which file is doing the `import` statement. So, in your case, you will probably have to do:

`from subdir import module1 as m1`

or something similar, irrespective of what folder that file which does the import is located in.

Comment: Not module imports. They depend on the paths configured in python, most notably the paths that appear in `sys.path`. Python will include the path of the script that is being run, but not the current working directory. If you happen to be in the ./proj/ directory when you run the script, current working directory is only coincidentally the same.

Comment: Exactly. That is infact the technically correct answer.